# How to bind MultiColumnTreeView from Syncfusion to BindingList(Of Object)?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, binding, syncfusion

Can you bind a BindingList(Of Object) to the Syncfusion MultiColumnTreeView (without For Loop)? If yes how? If not, can it be bound to a Dataset?

A VB.NET example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At present there is no support for this reported requirement in Syncfusion MultiColumnTreeView and it is needed to populate the MultiColumnTreeView by using looping / Iteration process.

We have logged feature report for this requirement and it will be available in any of our future releases.

Thanks
Syncfusion support